# passing array of structure to function in c++ and getting errror

Tags: c++, function, struct

Hi friends in my following program of c++. I am passing array of structure to function but getting errors in it. Can anybody help please. There are following erros in the program.

1.Constant expression required. 
2. Illegal structure operation.
3. Declaration syntax error.

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
void calc_price(struct c_items);
struct c_items
{
float name[80];
int quantity;
int price;
};
int main(void)
{
int num_items=3;
c_items obj[num_items]
calc_price(obj,num_items);
getch();
return 0;
}
void calc_price(c_items obj[],int num_items)
{
int i,n,total=0;
cout<<"Enter number of items = ";
cin>>n;
for(i=1;i<=num_items;i++)
{
cout<<"Enter name of item"<<i<<" = ";
cin>>obj[i].name;
cout<<endl<<"Enter price of item"<<i<<" = ";
cin>>obj[i].price;
cout<<endl<<"Enter quantity of item"<<i<<" = ";
cin>>obj[i].quantity;
}
cout<<endl<<endl<<"Retail value of inventory ";
for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
{
cout<<endl<<obj[i].name<<i<<"   "<<obj[i].price<<"$";
total=total+obj[i].price;
}
cout<<"Total retail value = "<<total<<"$";
}
```

Comment: please post the errors as well as the code

Comment: please try this code by `calc_price(c_items* obj,int num_items)`

Comment: Hi RobP, Question is updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;    // if you must

struct c_items
{
    std::string name;
    int quantity;
    int price;
};

void calc_price( c_items obj[], int num_items );

int main()
{
    const int num_items = 3;
    c_items obj[num_items];
    calc_price( obj, num_items );
    return 0;
}

void calc_price( c_items obj[], int num_items )
{
// etc.
```

In the `calc_price` function you need to be more careful with your array indices. The valid indices are `0` through `num_items - 1`, not `1` through `num_items`. And `5` is outside this range.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ and C arrays are passed by address (pointer) rather than by value. This has the side effect that the receiving function does not know how large the arrays are, even if you shape the argument to tell it.

C++ inherits something called "array-pointer equivalence" from C, which means that you can write

```
struct foo;
void fn(foo f[25]);
```

but that's just syntactic sugar. The compiler actually thinks you wrote:

```
void fn(foo * f);
```

(You will see some people write `foo* f`, some write `foo *f` and some write `foo f[]`; they all mean the same thing as the line above)

Here is a simple, complete, example of passing an array of structs (live demo http://ideone.com/qc4t53)

```
#include <cstddef>

struct Foo
{
    int m_i;  // 'm_' to distinguish a member variable.
};

int structFunc(Foo* foos, size_t numFoos);

int main()
{
    const size_t NumFoos = 10;
    Foo mainFoos[NumFoos];

    int i = structFunc(mainFoos, NumFoos);

    return 0;
}

int structFunc(Foo* foos, size_t numFoos)
{
    int retVal = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < numFoos; ++i) {
        foos[i].m_i = i;
        ++retVal;
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

More on array-pointer equivalence, from the [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrequiv.html)

Comment: Note that in C++ you can also pass arrays by reference, but this is only practical if you only have one size of array, or with a template function where the size is a template parameter.

Comment: +1 for explaining foo(bar*) and foo(bar[])/foo(bar[<n>] are equivalent.

Comment: I wouldn't call it "array-pointer equivalence" ; that suggests that arrays and pointers are equivalent when they are not.   You are describing a syntax quirk that exists only in a function's formal parameter list.

Comment: @MattMcNabb see the link to the C faq. That's what it is called, and it exists outside of parameter lists. `a[n]` and `*a+n` are equivalent whether a is `T a[...]` or `T * a`. As the faq points out, equivalent has a specific, subtle meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Second line of `main` should be `struct c_items obj[num_items];`

Declaration of void `calc_price(struct c_items);` doesn't match the definition/implementation `void calc_price(c_items obj[],int num_items)`

Comment: The second line of `main` is fine in that aspect, this being C++, but not in that it's using a VLA.

Comment: After modifying the declaration it is still not working

Answer (score 0):

you have five problems preventing the code from compiling:

1. `float name[` should really be `char name[`, otherwise the `operator>>` is not defined;
2. you missed a ";" in the main;
3. num_items in the main must be const (since you are using it for telling the compiler how long an array is);
4. there is no (valid) forward declaration of the function calc_price (i.e. `void calc_price(struct c_items);` should become `void calc_price(c_items obj[],int num_items);`
5. there is no forward declaration of the struct `c_items` when you first mention it in line 3.

Besides this, there is a number of different issues, the most important of which is: you must check, in `calc_price`, that the `cin`-ned `n` is no bigger than `num_items`